# Scipy Optimizer t is not defined

Tags: python, scipy

Hi I have this set of bond yield to maturity codes which im trying to debug. I keep getting t is not defined. Am lost whether this is a bug or it it is about ignoring declaring t as None variable

Would appreciate any help on this.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def bond_ytm(price, par, T, coup, freq=2, guess=0.05):
    freq = float(freq)
    periods = T*freq
    coupon = coup/100.*par/freq
    dt = [(i+1)/freq for i in range(int(periods))]
    ytm_func = lambda y: \
    sum([coupon/(1+y/freq)**(freq*t) for t in dt]) + \
    par/(1+y/freq)**(freq*t) - price

    return optimize.newton(ytm_func, guess)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your expression

```
sum([coupon/(1+y/freq)**(freq*t) for t in dt]) + par/(1+y/freq)**(freq*t) - price
                                                                       ^
                                                                   right here
```

The first `t` you get from `for t in dt`, but the second is outside the list comprehension - `t` is not defined.

Maybe you meant the second clause to be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry managed to resolve it. Careless mistake. Useful for anyone else finding bond_ytm

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize

def bond_ytm(price, par, T, coup, freq=2, guess=0.05):
    freq = float(freq)
    periods = T*freq
    coupon = coup/100.*par/freq
    dt = [(i+1)/freq for i in range(int(periods))]
    ytm_func = lambda y : \
    sum([coupon / (1 + y / freq)**(freq * t) for t in dt]) + \
    par / (1 + y / freq)**(freq * max(dt)) - price

    return optimize.newton(ytm_func, guess)

ytm = bond_ytm(95.0428, 100, 1.5, 5.75, 2)
print(ytm)
```